# SAS GPLOT nearby result

Tags: sas

Have a nice day to everyone here)
I hve number of gplot graphs. The output shows it "One after another".
Is is possible to output it nearby in a horizontal way? thank you!

```
%macro test;
%do i = 1 %to 2;
%_eg_conditional_dropds(WORK.SORTTempTableSorted&i.);
proc sql noprint;
select distinct name into: name from s&i.;quit;
   PROC SORT
     DATA=WORK.s&i.(KEEP=period SCORE RANGE_MID_2 RANGE_MID_1)
     OUT=WORK.SORTTempTableSorted&i.
     ;BY period;
RUN;
SYMBOL1
     INTERPOL=JOIN
     HEIGHT=10pt
     VALUE=NONE
     LINE=1
     WIDTH=2
     CV = _STYLE_
;
SYMBOL2
     INTERPOL=JOIN
     HEIGHT=10pt
     VALUE=NONE
     LINE=1
     WIDTH=2
     CI=RED    
     CV = _STYLE_;
SYMBOL3
     INTERPOL=JOIN
     HEIGHT=10pt
     VALUE=NONE
     LINE=1
     WIDTH=2
     CI=YELLOW
     CV = _STYLE_
;
Legend1
     FRAME
     ;
Axis1
     STYLE=1
     WIDTH=1
     MINOR=NONE
;
Axis2
     STYLE=1
     WIDTH=1
     MINOR=NONE
;
TITLE;
TITLE1 "&_name";
FOOTNOTE;

PROC GPLOT DATA = WORK.SORTTempTableSorted&i.
;
PLOT SCORE * period RANGE_MID_2 * period RANGE_MID_1 * period  /
OVERLAY
     VAXIS=AXIS1

     HAXIS=AXIS2
FRAME LEGEND=LEGEND1

RUN; QUIT;


%_eg_conditional_dropds(WORK.SORTTempTableSorted&i.);
TITLE; FOOTNOTE;
GOPTIONS RESET = SYMBOL;

%end;
%mend; %test;
```

This is am example when I generate 2 gplots. I did not make such reports before and do not know how to control the position of object.

Comment: How much 'horizontal' do you want ? Are the plots from separate GPLOT steps or different plots from BY statements of a single step?  What is your ODS destination ? Have you looked at ODS LAYOUT ? How about GREPLAY with TEMPLATE ?

Comment: Please provide your code and an example with dummy data if possible so we can help.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I want for Example 8 gplots in one A4 list format as a result. A am using GPLOT with macro processor to generate n - numbers of GPLOT code.

Comment: @Richard Richard thank you for ODS LAYOUT thing. I guess I found the answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can have either an Absolute ODS Layout or a Gridded ODS Layout. I recommend the gridded layout since you have a generic macro that generates the code for you.

You will find these two documents very useful to get your layout correct, both documentations includes working code. 
[SAS ODS TipSheet](https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/Tipsheet_ods_layout.pdf) and [SAS ODS Paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/159-31.pdf).

Example from SAS Tipsheet:

```
ods pdf file='gridded.pdf';
/* You can change or add rows=2 */
ods layout gridded columns=2 width=5in column_gutter=.25in style={background=lightgray};
 ods region style={background=lightblue};
/* Column One */
 proc means data=sashelp.class mean; run;
 ods region width=2in style={background=lightblue};
/* Column Two */
 proc print data=sashelp.class(obs=5 keep=name age); run;
ods layout end;
ods pdf close;
```